# Blender 2.8+ set pass index for object?

Tags: objects, workflow, render-passes

I am aware that in the Data API region I can locate the objects and set their object pass index but it is a fairly tedious exercise. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Properties Editor, in the Object tab:

[image]

You might also find it useful to use a very simple Python script to set different object indices for multiple objects(all selected in this case) at once:

```
import bpy

some_starting_number = 15

for i,o in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects):
    o.pass_index = i + some_starting_number
```

(You would copy this into a new text block in the Text Editor and hit Run Script with some objects selected)